# Load CSS and JS files if newer version exists on server

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net

I have an Web site written by ASP.NET . JS and CSS files are cached by client browsers default. Is there a way, I want to browser cache js and css first, but I want to browser download and cache if newer js and css files. It may be possible , Control date modified.

I make change into head tag like ‘myscript.js?v=300’ ,  at this time browser load js everytime. I want to browser load js only once if files are newer.

Comment: Just add a new filename for updated files and it will work...

Comment: it is not practice. This web site is developping every time

Comment: gulp has a feature to minify and give the files a fingerprint, were, whenever the code changes, the fingerprint is different and the browser will download the new version because the url is different. https://gulpjs.com/

Comment: @Kevinyudo You asked for a way to cache files, you updated, only once. Thats the way to go. Even Files with versioning-parameters aren‘t loaded by each browser directly. New filenames will be definitly.

Comment: ı have used myscript.js?v=300. But  every time browser load this file. Not make only once

Comment: @Kevinyudo Like i said... not every browser is supporting this. Use something like „myscript.300.js“ instead of querystring. You can do this programmaticly as well

Answer (score 0):

Caching is based on cache related HTTP header response from your server. You need a bundler like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/bundling-and-minification), `webpack` or `browsify`. Why you say not in practice while most bundler can generate different filename on every build. That is because browser maintain cache based on filename and the HTTP header, leaving only this two options for you to invalidate the cache. Try hard reload during your development.